# How to add Sharepoint Powershell to Console2

Tags: console, sharepoint-2010, console2

Salvete!  I want to add the Powershell Console for Sharepoint to the tablist in Console2.

I already have plain Powershell, but I want the Sharepoint Powershell snapin added automatically.

If I look at the properties of the Sharepoint Powershell Console shortcut, I see this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -NoExit  " & ' C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\\sharepoint.ps1 ' "
```

but that doesn't work in Console2, so I tried this, which doesn't work either:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -PSConsoleFile "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\psconsole.psc1"  -NoExit  " & ' C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\\sharepoint.ps1 ' "
```

Whenever I try, it will load Powershell, but not the Sharepoint Console.  I get this:

```
Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell' is not installed on this machine.
At C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\SharePoint.ps1:3 char:13
+ Add-PsSnapin <<<<  Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand
```

I [tried this](https://vintentou.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/error-the-windows-powershell-snap-in-microsoft-sharepoint-powershell-is-not-install/) out, too.

Anybody know?

**[update]**

I read that it IS possible to load the 64bit Powershell by inserting

`%SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

into the `Shell` field in Console2's settings.  However, if I tack on the ending, `-NoExit add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell`, I still get the error for the sharepoint snapin.  However, System Explorer says that is a 32 bit application!

The 64bit powershell is here, believe it or not:

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`

Comment: Give a try to ConEmu: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560

Comment: Nice app.  I'll look into that.

Comment: I guess nobody knows how to do it with Console2!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the 64-bit version of Console2. The 32-bit version will start the 32-bit version of PowerShell, and as previously reported, the 32-bit versi

Comment: Ah!  Good point!  Sharepoint demands 64bit in the first place.  I think that is the clencher.  I was using the 32bit version.

Comment: Any idea where to get a 64 bit version?  I don't find it on Sourceforge.

Comment: However, I CAN load the 64bit Powershell by setting the `Shell` path to: `%SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.  But it doesn't help with the Sharepoint snapin.

Comment: Here is the link to the 64bit version of Console2:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/files/console-devel/2.00/

Comment: Okay, got 64bit Console2.  I still have the same problem.

Comment: If anyone is following this, After you have 64bit Console2, you need to load 64bit Powershell (see the details in my question) and THEN sharepoint powershell WILL work in Console2.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the command in a batch file; it may be a command line interpretation problem within Console2 because of the quotes and ampersand.

Get it working by double clicking on the batch file in Windows Explorer; then, provide the path of the batch file in Console2.

Comment: Same thing.  I posted the error I receive.  It is the same error whether I use the (working) batch file, or the entry in Console2.